# Python Selenium Get the elements just above of my input Variable

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have as input `A[1]='International Round'`, I'm trying to find A[1] on the HTML code and after get the values 221.35 and -132.50 (will be saved at A[2] and A[3] respectively).
I tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@title, '%s' % A[1])]//*[contains(@class,'PR')]")` but doesn´t find the element. Below is the HTML Code. Thanks in advance for any help!!.

```
<td>    
<td>
<td>
  <a id="ol-s-28647620-a" class="Results " href="javascript:$M('ol').onPoints('s',28647620,'a',221.35)">
    <span class="PR">221.35</span>
    <span class="PM">-132.50</span>
    <span class="PL" title="International Round">International Round</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//` in `xpath` is going to children elements, not siblings. In your case use `preceding-sibling`

```
siblings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@title, '%s')]/preceding-sibling::span", % A[1])
A[2] = siblings[0].text
A[3] = siblings[1].text
```

Comment: Thank so so much, I've been days struggling with this. May you please recommend me a good book or online material for Selenium Python?

Comment: You are welcome :). I don't know any books for Selenium, and I'm not working with Python anyway (I work with C# and Java). I found that the best way to learn is to get stuck on something and look for the answer ;). @Johnny007